# Does the series $\sum\frac{\ln n}{n^{2}}$ Converge?

Tags: calculus

Does the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$$
converge?

I'm searching for a solution that does not use the Integral test, Stirling, L’Hôpital or functions theorems.

I tried ratio test, and also comparing it to another series.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the series is $-\zeta^' (2)$.

Comment: Please put your entire question in the body of your message.

Comment: @Arturo:Ok, I will.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why we're avoiding L'Hopital? It makes this vastly easier (in the sense that it's used often to prove david's answer below).

Comment: @mixedmath: Some analysis classes cover sequences/series before functions, maybe this problem comes from such a class....

Comment: Building off of @Eric's comment, $-\zeta(2)$ has a [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant): $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(12\ln A-\gamma-\ln(2\pi)\right)$, where $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

Comment: Since $\int \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx = C-\frac{1+\ln x}{x}$ you can get an approximation by adding up $n$ initial terms plus a adjustment of about $\frac{1+\ln n}{n}$ to give a series sum of about $0.937548$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can show that $\ln n\leq \sqrt n$ if $n$ is large enough. Now you can readily deduce that the series converges.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the condensation test for series whose terms are positive and weakly decreasing.

You replace the sum 
$$\sum_n a_n$$ by $$\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$$ and check that it converges.

Edited to add details:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^2} \longrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k \frac{\ln 2^k}{2^{2k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k \ln 2}{2^k}$$

The last sum converges by the ratio test, or by identifying it as the derivative of a geometric series evaluated at $q=1/2$.

Comment: I tried that before, It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: $2^ka_{2^k}=\frac{k\ln 2}{4^k}$ and the ratio test shows that $\sum_k2^ka_{2^k}$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different style of answer, which may be useful to some.

$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$, the Riemann zeta function, is analytic on $\Re(s)>1$.  This is because on any half plane $\Re(s)>1+\epsilon$, it is a uniformely convergent series of analytic functions.  Its derivative, $$\zeta^{'}(s)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log n n^{-s}$$ then also converges on all of $\Re(s)>1$.  Now, notice that your sum is $-\zeta^{'}(2).$