# Is the given series convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

The infinite series   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a^{n} \log n} {n^{2} } $ converges if and only if

(A) $a ∈ [−1, 1)$

(B) $a ∈ (−1, 1]$

(C) $a ∈ [−1, 1]$

(D) $a ∈ (−∞, ∞)$

*My attempt:*  The correct answer is option A) because if $a=1$,
$$\lim_{n\to ∞}a^{n}= ∞ .$$ So the correct option is A)  that is  $a ∈ [−1, 1)$.

Is my answer is correct or not, please verify and tell me the solution, I would be more than thankful.

Comment: If $a=1$ then $a^n =1 \to 1$ as $n$ increases

Comment: @ChinnapparajR,,yes,,i write this

Comment: @ Henry,,im not getting ur idea,,,how it will converges to 1

Comment: If $a=1$ then $a^n=1$ for all $n$ and you are looking at $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac { \log n} {n^{2} }$ which does converge, in fact to about $0.937548$.  So option A is wrong.

Comment: Thanks ,,@Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the ratio test :

$$ \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\left| \frac{a^{n+1}\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}.\frac{n^2}{a^n \log n} \right|$$

$$  =\left| a.\frac{\log (n+1)}{\log n}.\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^2 \right|$$

$$\rightarrow \vert a \vert$$ so the given series converges if $\vert a \vert<1.$

Also if $a=1$, then then given series becomes $\sum \frac{\log n}{n^2}$, which is converges(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/does-the-series-sum-frac-ln-nn2-converge) )

If $a=-1$, then then given series becomes $\sum \frac{(-1)^n\log n}{n^2}$, which is absolutely converges and hence converges

so the answer is $a\in [-1,1]$

Comment: thanks a lot @ chinnapparaj   but liitle bit confuse  $$\lim_{n\to ∞}a^{n}= ∞ $$  if a = 1...if a=1  and $1^{∞}  = ∞$

Comment: when $a\in (-1,1)$, then $a^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. When $a=1$, the $a^n=1^n=1$, a constant sequence which tends to $1$

Comment: thanks a lot once again@ Chinnapparaj R