# Find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n(n- \ln n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the following sum : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n }{n(n- \ln n)}$

I couldn't find any way to solve.

I just want a hint, how to initiate?

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions? By the way the sum does not seem to have a closed form.

Comment: @ClementYung Using '$$' makes the post easier to read.

Comment: An answer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/does-the-series-sum-frac-ln-nn2-converge) suggests that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^2} = - \zeta' (2)$.

Comment: What convinces you to believe that this sum has a closed form? Notice that your sum can be rephrased as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n(n-\log n)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \zeta^{(k)}(k+1). $$

Comment: Did your friend give you this problem? Or is it from somewhere else?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bi+%3D+1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+ln%28i%29%2F%28i%28i-ln%28i%29%29%29

Comment: @Toby Mak, this is from "Problems in Mathematical Analysis 1"by W. J. Kaczor

Comment: To solve the problem, hint is given that $ 0≤\ln n /(n- \ln n) <1, $ so sum is zero.

Comment: I think you mean the sum converges, not that the sum is zero?

Comment: The exact words of book are " observe that $ 0 ≤ \ln n/(n- \ln n) <1 , n \in N $ thus $S = 0$." And they have denoted the sum by $S$ in all other problems.

Comment: So basically you're supposed to check the convergence of the sum?

Comment: @LeBlanc According to the book, the sum is zero.

Comment: The book is wrong then (see the bellow answer). Or perhaps it was a typo and they wanted to say that the limit of the general term is zero (which is true from what they suggested to observe).

Comment: Interestingly, numerically this sum is very close to $1+\gamma/2$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant.

Answer (score 4):

I checked the actual problem (Problem 3.1.5.(b) of $\text{[1]}$, see also [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt77w.png)). Its exact formulation is as follows:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left[ \frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n} \right]. $$

Now, in this textbook, the bracket $[\cdot]$ is exclusively used for the greatest integer function. In other words, $[x] = \lfloor x \rfloor$. Now the hint perfectly makes sense, because

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n} < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left\lfloor \frac{\ln n}{n - \ln n} \right\rfloor = 0 $$

and the sum is zero.

---

$\text{[1]}$ Kaczor, Wiesława J., and Maria T. Nowak. *Problems in Mathematical Analysis: Real numbers, sequences, and series.* Vol. 1. American Mathematical Soc., 2000., p64

Comment: This should be mentioned with this problem in the book. By the way thanks, now that hint makes sense :).

Answer (score 3):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n(n-\ln n)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}
{n-\ln n}- \frac{1}{n} \right)\sim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} (1+\frac{\ln n}{n}+\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^2}+ \frac{\ln^3 n}{n^3}...) -\frac{1}{n}\right).$$ $$\implies S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\ln n}{n^2}+\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^3}+ \frac{\ln^3 n}{n^4}+...\right)=-\zeta'(2)+....$$ As per  the suggestion of @Toby Mak above.

Further, using $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}= \zeta(z) \implies 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{\ln^{k} n}{n^z} =\zeta^{(k)}(z)$$
It comes the same result as predicted by @Sangchui Lee above here in his comment as $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \zeta^{(k)} (k+1)$$

However, numeric strongly suggests a value of 1.28495... for S which is very close to $1+\gamma/2~~!$, where $\gamma$ is the Eular number equal to 0.5772...$

Comment: I'm amazed the proof is this short, but could you explain your third step?

Comment: Oh, is it because both functions are around $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: The third step is the binomial approxinmation $\frac{1}{n(1-\ln n/n)} \approx \frac{1}{n} (1-\ln n /n)^{-1}.$